# How can I realize 2D-Graphics in MFC application in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, mfc

How can I realize 2D-Graphics in MFC application in C++? If there are any classes or libraries please give me a reference to appropriate article in MSDN. Can I use GDI+ in Visual C++ in MFC application? Can I use Direct2D in Visual C++ in MFC application? I work in MS VS 2013 Ultimate. Any help will be appreciate highly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **Direct2D** is natively supported by **MFC** framework by `CHwndRenderTarget` class:

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
class CDemoView : public CScrollView
{
    CHwndRenderTarget m_renderTarget;
    std::shared_ptr<CD2DBitmap> m_spBitmap;
    // ...
};

int CDemoView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CScrollView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    HRESULT hr = m_renderTarget.Create(m_hWnd);
    return SUCCEEDED(hr) ? 0 : -1;    
}

void CDemoView::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CScrollView::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    if(m_renderTarget.IsValid())
    {
        m_renderTarget.Resize(CD2DSizeU(cx, cy));
    }
}

void CDemoView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    if(m_renderTarget.IsValid())
    {
        // initiate drawing on render target
        m_renderTarget.BeginDraw();
        // clear background using white color
        D2D1_COLOR_F color = {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}; // r, g, b, a
        m_renderTarget.Clear(color);
        if((nullptr != m_spBitmap) && m_spBitmap->IsValid())
        {
            // apply translation transform according to view's scroll position
            CPoint point = GetScrollPosition();
            D2D1_MATRIX_3X2_F matrix = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation((float)-point.x, (float)-point.y);
            m_renderTarget.SetTransform(matrix);
            // draw the bitmap
            CD2DSizeF size = m_spBitmap->GetSize();
            m_renderTarget.DrawBitmap(m_spBitmap.get(), CD2DRectF(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
        }
        // ends drawing operations 
        HRESULT hr = m_renderTarget.EndDraw();
        // if the render target has been lost, then recreate it
        if(D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET == hr)
        {
            m_renderTarget.ReCreate(m_hWnd);
        }
    }
}
```

The **GDI+** is also supported:

```
// init GDI+
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
```

Here is the way to use it with GDI device context:

```
CPaintDC dc(this);
Graphics graphics(dc.hdc); 
Pen MyPen(Color(255, 0, 255, ));  // A green pen, with full alpha
graphics.DrawLine(&pen, 0, 0, 200, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside what Andrew already suggested:

MFC has even more built-in support for **Direct2D** library (also for related **DirectWrite**).

Call **CWnd::EnableD2DSupport**, for example in WM_CREATE message handler, then it's no more necessary to create the render target yourself, to resize it, to call

1. BeginDraw
2. EndDraw

to recreate the render target if it has been lost and so on.

See more details in this short article: [MFC Support for Direct2D – Part 2](http://codexpert.ro/blog/2014/10/13/mfc-support-for-direct2d-part-2/)